# Binding KeyUp Event with Parameter

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, telerik-grid, commandparameter

I'm using a RadGridView in WPF (VB.Net) and I set to it an EventBinding like this :

```
<telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
    <telerik:EventBinding Command="{Binding CommandDeleteFolderRSP}" EventName="KeyUp"
                   CommandParameter="Delete" />
</telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
```

=> I want to bind a command if user wants to delete the selected row.

The problem is that all of the keys are fired the command, not only the 'Delete' key.

What is my error ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should to bind the command with the Deleting event like :

```
<telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
    <telerik:EventBinding Command="{Binding CommandDeleteFolderRSP}" EventName="Deleting" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
</telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
```

And for your command, you can use it like :

```
Private Sub DeleteFolderRSP(ByVal p_parameter As Object)
    Dim args As GridViewDeletingEventArgs = TryCast(p_parameter, GridViewDeletingEventArgs)

    If (condition) Then
        'Do Something
    Else
        args.Cancel = True 'Cancel the deleting operation
    End If
End Sub
```

Your RadGridView should :

- Not have *IsReadOnly* property set to true, else the *Deleting* event should not be fired.
- Has *CanUserDeleteRows* property set to true